# Remove the .html extension by using lamda edge - aws S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to remove the .html extension from using lambda edge.   it would be a lot easier to write

```
 const redirects = {
    '/about':                           '/about',
    '/contact.html':                    '/contact',
    '/start.html':                      '/start',
```

I been racking my brain about this for so long.  None of this works.  My brain is dead now.  So I am asking for help

The site is stored on S3 and is using cloudfront.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-edge-workshops/tree/master/Workshop1/Lab4_PrettyUrls

Answer (score 0):

There's not any built-in feature that allows this operation, but there's a method you can try to accomplish your target.

Don't name the file as **index.html**, just name it as **index**. Web browsers never care about the file extension you have, especially if the content of the file is correct. As long as the content type is set to text or html when the object is uploaded to S3, this works perfectly. And if you are using the console, you will have to set that manually because its not assumed automatically.

Comment: you can refer to this link and try the solution 2 or 3. Check if this works for you.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=796961&tstart=0

Comment: shikh Would you know of a sample code?  For Option 3. Using CloudFront and Lambda@Edge in front of the bucket in the link you provided?

Comment: option 1 worked for me so I never tried option 3, but your case seems to be matched with option 3 so I insist you to try again with option 3 from scratch. I hope this works at last.